# How can I iterate over big amount of files from S3, decompress each of them and pass them as Stream?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, gzip, inputstream

So currently, my code iterates over huge amount of files (.ndjson.gzip). 
During the iteration, each file converted into string and this string inserted to an hashset.

My Originally idea was to stream all files, so that the end user could manipulate this stream as he wishes. 
Also, it is a huge chunk of data, so I though, it will be much faster to stream all the files one after the other.

1.How can I implement my idea?

2.For example, how can I return from a function ( getAllFiles()) a stream, so that I could print the content?

```
public class ServiceGzipped {
  HashSet<String> getAllFiles() throws IOException {
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();

    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("some-bucket-name").withPrefix("some-prefix");
    ListObjectsV2Result result;


    do {
        result = client.listObjectsV2(request);

        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(summary.getKey() + " : " + summary.getSize());
            String s = downloadFromAWS(summary.getKey());
            hashSet.add(s);
        }

        String token = result.getNextContinuationToken();
        System.out.println(token);
        request.setContinuationToken(token);
    } while (result.isTruncated());

    return hashSet ;
}



String downloadFromAWS(String file) {
    S3Object s3Object = client.getObject(bucketName, file);
    String output = "";

    try {
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream= new GZIPInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent());

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String readed;
        while ((readed = in.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println(readed);
            output +=readed;
        }

        return output;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you considered Java [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Where does the variable `client` come from?

Comment: @Boris i create a connection to amazons3 client. It is a private and final attribute

Comment: @Boris I considered using Stream API, but I'm not really sure, how should I integrate it.

Comment: Please add `client` and other attributes if missing to the class. How have you considered it? Can you share any code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quiet sure how should I create a stream out of either GZIPInputStream, InputStreamReader or BufferedReader.
If you could give me some hint, on how can I use stream here, would be really helpful .  @Boris